# How can I recover lost secure notes in Keychain?

Tags: macos, keychain

I have been having problems is Messages.  One post suggested chucking your `login.keychain`.  This caused my secure notes to vanish.

Restoring this file from time machine (`~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`) did not help.

In answer to comment below:

Quit Keychain Access
Renamed login.keychain
Restored from the 7:31 backup this morning.
Restored `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple/keychainaccess.plist`

Restarted Keychain Access

No secure notes.

Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite

Comment: What exactly did you do and what do you mean by "*did not help*"?

Answer (score 2):

Stupid, silly me.

The left column has a pane for Keychains and a pane for categories.

The keychain pane has

- login
- local items
- System
- System Roots.

The Category pane has

- All Items
- Passwords
- Secure Notes
- My Certificates
- Keys
- Certificates.

These two are in essence multipied together.  That is, ANY of the keychains can have any of the categories.

In my wanderings I was somehow clicked into local items instead of login.  I had not created a local items secure note, so of course secure notes was blank.

Embarrassing as it is, I'm leaving this up for future klutzes.